# import data between specific times from consecutive days

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, birt

In BIRT Report (**which executes query for 10 minutes automatically - 24x7**), I would like to report data of datatype "Timestamp", which I import from a table in oracle databank using query. Let's say I have a table with name "table 1". Table 1 contains a column with name "column1" of datatype timestamp. The data in column1 is from a machine which runs continuously (24x7 - 365 days).

**Everyday** in the report, I would like to present only 24 hours data, which is between 05:30:00 (present day) and 05:30:00 (next day).

```
SELECT column1 from table 1
WHERE coulmn1 = SYSDATE - INTERVAL '24' hour;
```

Extracting data of last 24 hours or days or months is easy, but how to define a logic in where statement, which takes the actual systemtime as a reference and provides data between 05:30 (present day) and 05:30 (next day).

For Example: 
The automatic execution of query at 01:00:00 (or 1 AM) should show the data from previous day (05:30:00) to present (01:00:00)

The automatic executin of query at 08:00:00 (or 8 AM) should show the data from actual day (05:30:00 to 08:00:00).

Any help how to define a logic in where statement will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)` to trunate it back to midnight and then add an `INTERVAL`:

```sql
SELECT column1
FROM   table1
WHERE  column1 >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '0 05:30' DAY TO MINUTE
AND    column1 <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + INTERVAL '1 05:30' DAY TO MINUTE;
```

If you want to handle the case when the `SYSDATE` is before `05:30` then:

```sql
SELECT column1
FROM   table1
WHERE  column1 >= TRUNC( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE )
                  + INTERVAL '0 05:30' DAY TO MINUTE
AND    column1 <  TRUNC( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE )
                  + INTERVAL '1 05:30' DAY TO MINUTE;
```

And if you do not want to show future times then:

```sql
SELECT column1
FROM   table1
WHERE  column1 >= TRUNC( SYSDATE - INTERVAL '05:30' HOUR TO MINUTE )
                  + INTERVAL '0 05:30' DAY TO MINUTE
AND    column1 <= SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Thank you @MTO. There will be always two scenarios - one is when the sysdate is > 05:30 and sysdate < 05:30. When the automatic execution of query is at 02:00:00 then it should import data which is between 05:30:00 (of previous day) and 02:00:00 (present day). when the automatic execution of query is at 06:00:00 then it should import data which is between 05:30:00 (present day) and 06:00:00 (present day).

Comment: @Chanti The second and third queries should automatically handle the difference between the two cases. You can try it putting in different static timestamp values instead of `SYSDATE`.